# Google Charts with multiple dashboards more than 1 chart on same page

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Chaps,

I have managed to create a Google Chart with a Dashboard control. You can pick a value and it will show data for it just fine in a nice Pie Chart. This is all working perfectly.

My problem is I need more than 1 of these on a page but I am unable to recode it to achieve this aim.

I.e There would be another Pie Chart using it's own data table, and with it's own dashboard control.

It looks like this:

[image: Chart]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Variant', 'Data', 'Percentage'],
      ['Ring Size','Size 3', 30],
      ['Ring Size','Size 4', 20],
      ['Ring Size','Size 5', 10],
      ['Ring Size','Size 6', 15],
      ['Ring Size','Size 7', 10],
      ['Ring Size','Size 8', 15],
      ['Extra Info','Jewellery', 100],
      ['Colour','Black', 40],
      ['Colour','Biege', 30],
      ['Colour','Red', 15],
      ['Colour','Green', 15]
    ]);


    var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control1',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Variant',
        'ui': {
        'allowNone': false,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });


    // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1',
      'options': {
        'width': '300',
        'height': '300',
        'chartArea': {top: 0, left: 0, width:"100%", height:"100%"},
        'legend': {position: 'right', alignment: 'center'},
      },
      'view': {'columns': [1, 2]}
    });


    // Create the dashboard.
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
      bind(regionPicker, barChart).
      draw(data);
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
```

Comment: You didn't include your attempted code, but I might just be that you must use different container ids for each instance, control2 and chart2.  Make a function out of the whole dashboard generator, and give it parameters that will provide the unique data and ids.

Comment: like @dlaliberte I fail to see the issue above. It looks like your code is fine to generate the chart, so what is the issue you are running in to? What about this is failing to work? If you do just this one individually, does it work or not? As stated above, if you use the same `<div>` names for both dashboards, one will overwrite the other.